# AWS pipeline and Github

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, pipeline

I'm new to AWS CI/CD. We current have one wordpress website running on two AWS EC2 instances, the live site is on the AWS EC2 instance for live, and the staging one is with the development EC2 instance and I put part of my codes on Github, getting rid of files like plugins. The github repository has two branches, one is development and another is Master. I current want to create one pipeline so once I push code to development branch, it will auto update the code of the staging site and once I merge the development with the Master branch, the code on the live site will be updated.

This is not the new instance from AWS elastic beanstalk at the beginning, so can I set up the AWS pipeline on the exsiting EC2 instances? and will that overwrite the other files not tracked by Git? I don't want those plugins files overwriten when I set up the pipeline.

If they're all possible, how should I set up it? Anyone can give me a logic brief?

Comment: You should consider checking in your plugins to your repo. This makes deployment atomic, with no other code dependency

Answer (score 0):

> I current want to create one pipeline

Sadly you can't do this. You need one CodePipeline (CP) for each branch. Thus you need two CPs, one for master branch and second for the dev branch.

> This is not the new instance from AWS elastic beanstalk at the beginning, so can I set up the AWS pipeline on the existing EC2 instances?

Yes, you have to use CP's [Elastic Beanstalk (EB) deploy action provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/integrations-action-type.html#w2aac11b9c13c15).  Since you have two EB environments, each CPs will deploy to its respective EB instance (one for master, and second for dev).

> and will that overwrite the other files not tracked by Git? I don't want those plugins files overwriten when I set up the pipeline.

Not sure what do you mean, but during deployment everything that is in the application folder on EB (`/var/app/current`) will be deleted and replaced with new version of your application.

Comment: The problem is at the beginning before I took over the project, they didn't set up Elastic Beanstalk so there is EC2 only. Can I set EB enviornment now after the EC2 instance created?

Comment: @Moon EB instances are heavily customized with bunch of EB specific software. I think easier would be to migrate your application to EB, but then this may require some changes to it, as EB has its own requirements.

Comment: Since there is no EB, how can I point the location if I set up the CP? What I put on the git is only part of the code, like /var/www/wp-content, and there are other folders, like /var/www/wp-plugins. Can I set the CP only work for wp-content folder but not others?

Comment: @Moon AWS provides [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html) on running WP on EB. You would have to check it for all the details.